# Hide input after append(after)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create input fields with button. But what I want is, when input field is created, I want hide created input field with the same button. I tried `slideToggle` function, but that didn't worked very well.

```
<button type="button" id="addEmail" "class1"></button>

$('#addEmail').one('click', function () {
    var dummy = '<input type="text">';
    $('.email').after(dummy); //creating input after class 'email'
    $(this).addClass('less-inputs'); //Changing buttons css
});
```

Comment: it is working.. https://jsfiddle.net/qdgm05t4/3/

Comment: I dont want hide the button, i want hide the input field with same button. My spelling mistake in question, sorry.

Comment: yeah, then I misunderstood you question.

Answer (score 1):

The most concise way would be to create a jQuery context to represent your `dummy` element instead of a mere HTML string.

Something like:

```
var $dummy = $('<input type="text">');
$('.email').after($dummy);
$dummy.addClass('less-inputs');
```

Or even shorter:

```
$('<input type="text">')
     .addClass('less-inputs')
     .insertAfter($('.email'));
```

Comment: Why not suggesting `var $dummy = $('<input type="text" class="less-inputs">');`, but adding it using Jquery ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I would argue that there are at least 4 possible ways to add the `class` to the to-be-appended element. *I* chose `addClass()` because I wanted to demonstrate that method chaining still returns the original context.

Comment: Hm, right. But I wanted to make sure myself that my thinking/approach is correct or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the input within the HTML and simply show/hide it on button click.

If you want to create it dynamically you can add an ID to the input to check its existence. If the input exists you remove it, otherwise you add it.